# Draw Shape in canvas does not appear when going back and forth

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I have canvas panel that i can drawl circle and rectangle with the option to change their color and fillcolor. However, when i go and press on back button (history) and go again to the canvas area - i can see the list of my drawing shapes, their colors and points, But somehow they are not displayed on the canvas, When i change a color or delete on of the shapes the other shapes aer been shown again. I am using angular so maybe this is something with the lifecycle, but its not sure since the data does coming . What am i missing. here is the init of my markerService. i can see al the data, even the list of the markers are displayed in the html but not shapes are drawn.

```
InitMarkersService(strokeColor:FormControl,fillColor :FormControl): any {
 this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
 
 this.fillColor = fillColor
 console.log(this.markers)
if(!this.currentDocument || this.currentDocument != this.docService.CurrentDocumentId)
{
  this.currentDocument= this.docService.currentDocumentId
  this.cnavasComm.GetMarkers(this.userID, this.currentDocument).subscribe(res =>this.InitMarkersRespond(res))
  this.currentlyEdited = new Array()

}
console.log(this.markers)
this.markers$.next(this.markers);
```

}

now there is the component and under the function ngafterviewinit there is this code:

```
this.drawingService.InitSize(this.container, this.CanvasFreeDrew, this.canvasContainer)
this.drawingService.Init()
this.drawingService.MouseDown().subscribe((evt) => (this.prevPos =evt))
this.drawingService.FreeDraw().subscribe((evt) => (this.FreeDraw(evt)))
this.drawingService.GetPoints().subscribe(array => this.AddNewShape(array))
this.cx = this.CanvasFreeDrew.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
this.ctx = this.canvasContainer.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
this.cxSelected = this.canvasSelected.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
this.cxSelected.lineWidth = 5
this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4  
this.cx.globalAlpha = 0.7
this.ctx.lineWidth = 3

this.markerService.markers$.subscribe( (markers:any) => {console.log(markers),this.showDocumentMarkers(markers)})
```

the last line on that function runs before the start of the function and thats what makes my shapes unvisible

[this picture show the drawing as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjBdY.jpg)

[the second picture is when i click on the brwoser "back" and go again to the canvas area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5gSC.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] please?

Comment: I dont know how without using all the code around. it works with calls to the .net side to get the data from the Db.

Comment: The idea is to minimize the code down to a simple runnable snippet that reproduces the problem. This isn't enough to offer concrete help yet.